# Derivative of quadratic form in NCAlgebra

Tags: matrix, symbolic, vector-calculus, ncalgebra

I installed the NCAlgebra package in the hope that it contains enough rules for symbolic work with most branch-matrix expressions.

```
<< NC`;
<< NCAlgebra`;
NCGrad[X^T ** A ** X, X]
```

The result obtained did not suit me.

```
A X + A T X
```

First, the package does not work with transposition. And secondly, it does not distinguish between vectors and matrices. What do I need to consider when working with it and how to get the correct result in the form:

$\frac{d}{dx}x^TAx=(A+A^T)x$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the documentation of `NCGrad`:

> IMPORTANT: The expression returned by NCGrad is the transpose or the 
> adjoint of the standard gradient. This is done so that no assumption 
> on the symbols are needed. The calculated expression is correct even 
> if symbols are self-adjoint or symmetric.

What you are looking for is therefore

```
SNC[X, A]
tp[NCGrad[tp[X] ** A ** X, X]]
```

which returns

> A ** X + tp[A] ** X

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it.

Comment: Oh, I have one more little question. How, using the `NCAlgebra`, to differentiate an expression of the following form: `Transpose[X].A[X].X`